# Ajax call loading everytime on page reload duplicating content

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Basically I load my homepage and one of my components is the following:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class BlogPostsWidget extends Component {
  render() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[orderby]=asc&filter&per_page=3&categories=1,2,3,11,258,378,447',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(post) {
          $( '.blog__body' ).append( '<div class="col-md-4"><div class="blog__body__article"><a target="_blank" href="' + post.link + '"><img class="card-img-top img-responsive lazy" src="' + post.ccw_thumbnail + '"></a><h2 class="bold text-center card-title">' + post.title.rendered + '</h2><div class="short-border"></div>' + post.excerpt.rendered + '<a target="_blank" class="black-link" href="' + post.link + '">READ MORE <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></div>' );
        });
      }
    });

    return (
      <div className="blog">
        <div className="blog__body">
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default BlogPostsWidget;
```

On initial page load everything is working fine. However if i click on my logo to re-render my homepage my `Ajax` call is firing again causing the same 3 blog posts to be loaded in after my already rendered ones

How do I make sure my `Ajax` script runs only once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, and put the ajax call inside that. It will get called only once just after the component rendering.

From [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request.